# Sending Big Endian formatted binary over the wire

Tags: c, network-programming, endianness

I was multicasting something like this before:

```
struct Message
{
    char     cat[3];
    uint64_t foo;
    uint16_t bar;
} __attribute((packed));

Message MESSAGE;

int main(void)
{
    //every now and then
    memcpy(MESSAGE.cat, bla, 3);
    MESSAGE.foo = varA;
    MESSAGE.bar = varB - varC;

    sendto(fd, &MESSAGE, sizeof(MESSAGE), 0, &sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr));
}
```

The claim on the receiver end is that they would get MESSAGE but `foo` and `bar` were scrambled even though `cat` was fine. And that they expect Big Endian for the integral values. So I changed my code to do this:

```
int main(void)
{
    //every now and then
    memcpy(MESSAGE.cat, bla, 3);
    MESSAGE.foo = bswap_64(varA);
    MESSAGE.bar = varB - varC;
    MESSAGE.bar = bswap_16(MESSAGE.bar);

    sendto(fd, &MESSAGE, sizeof(MESSAGE), 0, &sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr));
}
```

and the claim is still the same. How is this possible? Big vs Little endian is binary, if it wasn't before it should be now. Or is there something wrong in the logic above?

Comment: Is your sizeof(MESSAGE) 3+8+2 or what?  (how packed is it?) Suggest that the packing out your structure is not as the receiver expects.  IOW, not an endian issue, but a packing one.

Comment: Try to add some debug in your code. Are you sure to send the good informations?

Comment: If `bla` is an integer type, that would give an endian-dependency too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look up http://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohl

Convert things into network order then reconstruct.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the packet to a file before sending it - That way you can examine it.

Comment: About the padding: there's an `__attribute((packed));` in the code.

Comment: Edited my answer to remove paragraph about possibly not being packed